# PHP hash_hmac Can't get the same result as vb.net result HMACSHA

Tags: php, .net, vb.net

**VB.net code:**

```vb
Function HMACSHA(ByVal Key As String, ByVal Value As String)

   Dim objHMAC As New HMACSHA1(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Key))

   HMACSHA_Encrypt = (objHMAC.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Value)))

End Function
```

Example

```
Key         e.g. “RHBNow”
Value       e.g. “7090982.885183” based on custom hash algorithms
Hash value  e.g. bcf370bcbb6248c4d718ec17e5c6982477744f6a
```

**Php:**

```
$ha1='RHBNow';

$ha2=7090982.885183;

$binarySignature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1',$ha1,$ha2, true));

$urlSafeSignature = urlencode($binarySignature);
```

Result :

```
PS7%2FPqt95CtEEGeNsNOV1y%2FEaQ4%3D
```

Can't get the same result as vb.net result.

Answer (score 0):

please try the following:

```
<?php
$ha1 = "RHBNow";
$ha2 = "7090982.885183";
echo $hash = hash_hmac('sha1', $ha2, $ha1);
?>
```

Thanks.